# Java - Write call to socket output stream blocking in full duplex

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio, socketchannel

I'm writing a client server application and I want to both read and write on one socket from two different threads (one thread for reading, one for writing). I have the system nearly working, but there is one perplexing bug that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Reading and writing work perfect independent of each other, but when I start reading from the `Socket`'s `OutputStream` in one thread, all calls to write to the `InputStream` in a different thread block indefinitely.

I've written a small test program for quickly reproducing the issue and to eliminate as many external variables as I could. I use `java.nio`'s `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel` to set up the connection and I use `java.io`'s `Socket` (the underlying socket of a `SocketChannel`) for its ease of use with `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. The test program is designed to run twice; for the first run, the user inputs `s` to launch the server and on the second run the user inputs `c` to run the client.

**My question is:** Why does execution of the below program block on the second call to `objectOutput.writeObject( message );` in the `server()` method? (fourth to last line in that method)

I've included the expected outputs and actual outputs and what I think they mean below the program code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "localhost";
    private static final int WELL_KNOWN_PORT = 4000;

    public static void main( String... args ) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.print( "choose (s)erver or (c)lient: " );
        char choice = scanner.nextLine().charAt( 0 );
        switch ( choice ) {
        case 's':
            server();
            break;
        case 'c':
            client();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static void server() throws Exception {

        // initialize connection

        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.bind( new InetSocketAddress( WELL_KNOWN_PORT ) );
        System.out.println( "waiting for client to connect" );
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        System.out.println( "client connected" );
        socketChannel.configureBlocking( true );
        while ( !socketChannel.finishConnect() )
            Thread.sleep( 100 );
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

        // write first object to stream

        Message message = new Message( 1 );
        System.out.println( "writing first object to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message );
        System.out.println( "first object written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );

        // start reading in a separate thread

        new Thread( () -> {
            ObjectInput objectInput = null;
            try {
                objectInput = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Message messageIn = null;
            try {
                System.out.println( "reading on object input stream" );
                messageIn = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
                System.out.println( "read object on object input stream: " + messageIn );
            } catch ( ClassNotFoundException | IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println( messageIn );
        } ).start();
        Thread.sleep( 100 ); // allow time for object listening to start

        // write second object to stream

        message = new Message( 2 );
        System.out.println( "writing second object to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message ); // this call seems to block??
        System.out.println( "second object written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );
    }

    private static void client() throws Exception {

        // initialize connection

        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking( true );
        socketChannel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( IP_ADDRESS, WELL_KNOWN_PORT ) );
        while ( !socketChannel.finishConnect() )
            Thread.sleep( 100 );
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
        ObjectInput objectInput = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );

        // read first object

        System.out.println( "reading first object on object input stream" );
        Message message = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
        System.out.println( "read first object on object input stream: " + message );

        // read second object

        System.out.println( "reading second object on object input stream" );
        message = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
        System.out.println( "read second object on object input stream: " + message );

        // write confirmation message

        message = new Message( 42 );
        System.out.println( "writing confirmation message to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message );
        System.out.println( "confirmation message written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );
    }

    private static class Message implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5649798518404142034L;
        private int data;

        public Message( int data ) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + data;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

Expected output:

```
choose (s)erver or (c)lient: s
waiting for client to connect
client connected
writing first object to object output stream: 1
first object written to object output stream
object output stream flushed
reading on object input stream
writing second object to object output stream: 2
second object written to object output stream
object output stream flushed
read object on object input stream: 42
```

Actual output:

```
choose (s)erver or (c)lient: s
waiting for client to connect
client connected
writing first object to object output stream: 1
first object written to object output stream
object output stream flushed
reading on object input stream
writing second object to object output stream: 2
```

The application successfully sends the first object but blocks indefinitely on the second. The only difference I can see is that the second write call happens while a read operation is in process on a separate thread. My first instinct was that maybe `Socket`s don't support simultaneous reading and writing from different threads, but my search of Stack Overflow suggests that they do support this simultaneous operation (full duplex). This is the primary reason I'm confused with the operation of the above code.

**Client**

Expected output:

```
choose (s)erver or (c)lient: c
reading on object input stream
read first object on object input stream: 1
reading second object on object input stream
read second object on object input stream: 2
writing confirmation message to object output stream: 42
confirmation message written to object output stream
object output stream flushed
```

Actual output:

```
choose (s)erver or (c)lient: c
reading first object on object input stream
read first object on object input stream: 1
reading second object on object input stream
```

This confirms that the first object was successfully sent and received by the client. The client seems to be waiting on the second object which is never sent by the server due to this strange blocking behavior in the server.

Thanks so much in advance for any advice anyone may be able to give. I'm open to rewriting my code if full duplex is easily achievable in another manner, but If there is a solution using the above structure I would much prefer to stick with that for simplicity of not having to refactor large sections of code.

Comment: I'm running Java 9 in Eclipse Oxygen 1A if that is helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with this code I will have to take it line by line:

```
private static void server() throws Exception {

        // initialize connection

        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.bind( new InetSocketAddress( WELL_KNOWN_PORT ) );
        System.out.println( "waiting for client to connect" );

        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
```

There is nothing above that 'initializes a connection'. The client initializes the connection. This code *accepts* it.

```
        System.out.println( "client connected" );
        socketChannel.configureBlocking( true );
```

This is the default. You don't need to assert defaults.

```
        while ( !socketChannel.finishConnect() )
            Thread.sleep( 100 );
```

You shouldn't be calling this. `finishConnect()` is for *clients* that have called `connect()`, in *non-blocking* mode. You are a server, you haven't called `connect()`, and you aren't in non-blocking mode. And if you *are* a client in non-blocking mode you shouldn't call it in a loop with sleeps: you should use `Selector.select()` with `OP_CONNECT`.

```
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
```

As you are using blocking mode and output streams it is impossible to see why you are using `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel` at all, and as a matter of fact this is at least part of the problem. It is a little-known fact that streams derived from NIO channels use synchronization on the channel for both reading and writing, and they are therefore not full-duplex at all, even though the underlying TCP connection is. Remove all this and rewrite using `ServerSocket` and `Socket`.

```
        // write first object to stream

        Message message = new Message( 1 );
        System.out.println( "writing first object to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message );
        System.out.println( "first object written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );

        // start reading in a separate thread

        new Thread( () -> {
            ObjectInput objectInput = null;
            try {
                objectInput = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Don't write code like this. Code like the below that depends on the success of a prior `try` block like the above must be inside that `try` block. Otherwise for example the following code is liable to get `NullPointerExceptions`.

```
            Message messageIn = null;
            try {
                System.out.println( "reading on object input stream" );
                messageIn = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
                System.out.println( "read object on object input stream: " + messageIn );
            } catch ( ClassNotFoundException | IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Ditto.

```
            System.out.println( messageIn );
        } ).start();
        Thread.sleep( 100 ); // allow time for object listening to start

        // write second object to stream

        message = new Message( 2 );
        System.out.println( "writing second object to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message ); // this call seems to block??
        System.out.println( "second object written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );
    }
```

See above for why doing this in separate threads cannot work in the case of streams derived from NIO channels.

```
    private static void client() throws Exception {

        // initialize connection

        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking( true );
        socketChannel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( IP_ADDRESS, WELL_KNOWN_PORT ) );
        while ( !socketChannel.finishConnect() )
            Thread.sleep( 100 );
```

The last two lines above are pointless, because the connect *has* completed, because you're in blocking mode.

```
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
        ObjectInput objectInput = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );

        // read first object

        System.out.println( "reading first object on object input stream" );
        Message message = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
        System.out.println( "read first object on object input stream: " + message );

        // read second object

        System.out.println( "reading second object on object input stream" );
        message = (Message) objectInput.readObject();
        System.out.println( "read second object on object input stream: " + message );

        // write confirmation message

        message = new Message( 42 );
        System.out.println( "writing confirmation message to object output stream: " + message );
        objectOutput.writeObject( message );
        System.out.println( "confirmation message written to object output stream" );
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println( "object output stream flushed" );
    }
```

You can use the rest of this as-is, but again the NIO channels are pointless here. You may as well use `Socket`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback. That all makes a lot of sense. I originally started to use nio because I was going to write and read bytes manually. After that choice I went back to just plain sockets for the ease of use with object streams. The part about streams coming from a socket created with a SocketChannel being synchronized is exactly what I was after. Thanks again!

Comment: I can confirm. I made all of the changes suggested in your answer and my code runs flawlessly. I might return to nio some day for their Selectors and other features, but for this project at this time, this works great.